# Why the first call of the va_arg function get a strange number?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32f4, stm32cubemx

I'm developing  a firmware for my STM32 board based on a STM32F412RET6 processor with STM32CubeIde and FREERTOS .
When I call the `va_arg` function, of  the  `stdarg.h` library, for the first time  get me a strange number. Why?

The code:

```
void readFloat(int n, ...){
    int val;
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,n);

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        val=va_arg(vl,int);
    }

    va_end(vl);
}

/**
  * @brief  Function implementing the defaultTask thread.
  * @param  argument: Not used 
  * @retval None
  */
/* USER CODE END Header_StartDefaultTask */
void StartDefaultTask(void *argument)
{     
    readFloat(3, 1, 2, 3);
    for(;;)
    {
        osDelay(1);
    }
    /* USER CODE END 5 */ 
}
```

The debug result:

[image]

Comment: Did you actually step through the relevant assignment in the debugger?

Comment: The function can be optimized out by the compiler - it does nothing. Do you compile with debugging symbols and optimizations disabled? Try adding `volatile` to `val` definition.

Comment: The debugger usually highlights the *next* line that will run. So that line hasn't run yet and val is uninitialized!

Comment: @KamilCuk : Why!?

Comment: Try reading `val` _after_ it has been assigned I suggest.  The "strange number" is the non-deterministic value of an unitialised variable.  Your break-point is _before_ the call and assignment.  Declare `val` with initialisation to demonstrate that, e.g.: `int val = 0 ;`  The strange number is in fact 0xA5A5A5A5 which looks like stack filler used to detect the high-tide mark of stack usage.